# Draw images evenly spaced along a path in iOS

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

What I want to do is move my finger across the screen (touchesMoved) and draw evenly spaced images (perhaps CGImageRefs) along the points generated by the touchesMoved. I can draw lines, but what I want to generate is something that looks like this (for this example I am using an image of an arrow but it could be any image, could be a picture of my dog :) )  The main thing is to get the images evenly spaced when drawing with a finger on an iPhone or iPad.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have code that tracks the user's touch as they move their touch around the screen, it sounds like you want to detect when they have moved a distance equal to the length of your image, at which time you want to draw another copy of your image under their touch.

To achieve this, I think you will need to:

- calculate the length (width) of your image
- implement code to draw copies of your image onto your view, rotated to any angle
- each time the user's touch moves (e.g. in touchesMoved:):

  - calculate the delta of the touch each time it moves and generate the "length" of that delta (e.g. something like sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2))
  - accumulate the distance since the last image was drawn
  - if the distance has reached the length of your image, draw a copy of your image under the touch's current position, rotated appropriately (probably according to the vector from the position of the last image to the current position)

How does that sound?

Comment: Let me give it a try.  It never occurred to me to base the placement of the images on distance.  I was thinking I would need to add or adjust points on the path.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, will post the working code when I have it cleaned up. (You don't off the top of your head know how to calculate a proper vector do you :) )

Comment: Nice work on implementing this and posting your code. It looks like you'll need to offset your drawing a little to get the tip of your arrows to point to the base of the next one. Try calculating another vector, this time 90 degrees rotated from the image's orientation and length equal to half the width of your image, then add that vector to your currentPoint.x and .y and see how it looks.

Comment: I pretty much Forest Gumped my way through the vector thing. So is the images orientation the current angle ? Or do I create an arbitrary point that is half the width of my image away but 90 degrees to the right of ... well you see my understanding of vectors is only 45 minutes old :)

Comment: Yes! By "vector" I just meant an (x, y) location, as you've figured out, so now all you need to do is find the right offset to make your series of arrows look smooth. I haven't tested this, but it seems to me that shifting each arrow "left" or "right" by half its width should align them nicely, which is where the 90 degree rotation comes from: the "left"/"right" shift has to be relative to the arrow's orientation.

Comment: O.K., let me chew on that one for a while..  I'll update when I've figured it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

First of all HUGE props go out to Kendall.  So, based on his answer, here is the code to take a UIImage, draw it on screen along a path (not a real pathRef, just a logical path created by the points) based on the distance between the touches and then rotate the image correctly based on the VECTOR of the current and previous points.  I hope you like it:

First you need to load an image to be used as a CGImage over and over again:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrow.png" ofType:nil];
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
  image = CGImageRetain(img.CGImage);
```

make sure in your dealloc that you call

```
 CGImageRelease(image);
```

then in touchesBegan, just store the starting point in a var that is scoped outside the method (declare it in your header like this :) in this case I am drawing into a UIView

```
@interface myView : UIView {
    CGPoint lastPoint;
    }
@end
```

then in touches Began:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
```

}

and finally in touchesMoved, draw the bitmap to the screen and then when your distance has moved enough (in my case 73, since my image is 73 pixels x 73 pixels) draw that image to the screen, save the new image and set lastPoint equal to currentPoint

```
     -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
        currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

        double deltaX = lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x;
        double deltaY = lastPoint.y - currentPoint.y;

        double powX = pow(deltaX,2);
        double powY = pow(deltaY,2);

        double distance = sqrt(powX + powY);
        if (distance >= 73){

            lastPoint = currentPoint;

             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

            float angle = atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
            angle *= (M_PI / 180);


            CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y, 73, 73),[self CGImageRotatedByAngle:image angle:angle * -1]);
            CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
             drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            distance = 0;

        }

    }


    - (CGImageRef)CGImageRotatedByAngle:(CGImageRef)imgRef angle:(CGFloat)angle
{
    CGFloat angleInRadians = angle * (M_PI / 180);
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
    CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, transform);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                   rotatedRect.size.width,
                                                   rotatedRect.size.height,
                                                   8,
                                                   0,
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(bmContext, FALSE);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bmContext, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bmContext,
                          +(rotatedRect.size.width/2),
                          +(rotatedRect.size.height/2));
    CGContextRotateCTM(bmContext, angleInRadians);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bmContext,
                          -(rotatedRect.size.width/2),
                          -(rotatedRect.size.height/2));
    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                             rotatedRect.size.width,
                                             rotatedRect.size.height),
                       imgRef);

    CGImageRef rotatedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
    CFRelease(bmContext);
    [(id)rotatedImage autorelease];

    return rotatedImage;
}
```

this will create an image that looks like this :

[image]

Going to add the following (with some changes to the above code in order to try and fill in the voids where touchesMoved is missing some points when you move fast:

```
CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(100, 200);

CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(300, 100);



double deltaX = point2.x - point1.x;
double deltaY = point2.y - point1.y;

double powX = pow(deltaX,2);
double powY = pow(deltaY,2);

double distance = sqrt(powX + powY);

distance = 0;


for (int j = 1; j * 73 < distance; j++ )
{
    double x =  (point1.x + ((deltaX / distance) * 73 * j));
    double y =  (point1.y + ((deltaY / distance) * 73 * j));


    NSLog(@"My new point is x: %f y :%f", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Going to add the following (with some changes to the above code in order to try and fill in the voids where touchesMoved is missing some points when you move fast:

Comment: Thanks for you help,how can i plot the x and y points please suggest me

Comment: Why do you set distance=0 in the lowest code box before the for loop? How does the bottom-most code box help with the fast motion?