# How to draw an image along a curve

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have drawn a curve:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, cpx1, cpy1, cpx2, cpy2, finalPoint.x, finalPoint.y);
```

And now I want to draw an image multiple times along the path of the curve.

Is it possible to do that? If so, How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951142/draw-images-evenly-spaced-along-a-path-in-ios